# Use foil as dutch oven lid for loaf pan

Tags: bread, dutch-oven

Can I lay foil over the dough in a loaf pan, to contain moisture like a dutch oven?

I've practiced using cast iron dutch oven baking, but this time I would like to use a loaf pan, so I can cut the bread evenly.

Comment: It's worth noting that part of what makes a dutch oven special is the thickness/density of the walls... loaf pans don't have that thickness, so you're not going to get the same results at all. If you really want a covered loaf pan, you might consider looking for a pullman pan, though it's designed for a specific type of bread making.

Answer (score 1):

The lid on a Dutch oven retains heat and traps moisture as it evaporates from the bread, giving the loaf that beautiful artisan crust. Foil will neithe trap the moisture adequately, nor will it retain heat, but it will slow your crust from browning too quickly. If crust is what you’re going for, try adding a pan to the lower rack in your oven, then when you put your loaf in, pour a cup or two of cold water into the pan. The steam will approximate (but not equal) the steam that a professional oven creates.

One of your commenters suggested a Pullman loaf pan. It’s a box with a slide-off lid. It makes a perfectly square loaf that is perfect for sandwiches, but the crust and crumb more resemble store-bought white bread than, say, sourdough.